# S4 Wont turn on unless removing battery then turns off after 2 seconds

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, battery, boot

So, my Galaxy S4 turned off randomly today during charge. I attempted turning it back on via the power button but it would not respond.

Then I tried taking out the battery and replacing it, the device vibrates with the Galaxy S4 logo showing up for about a couple seconds, then the screen goes blank again.

I even tried placing a battery from a different S4 - still doesn't work.

Anybody know what's wrong with my device?

**Edit**: Flat Surface trick doesn't work. It vibrates sometimes but then it turns off.

Comment: Have you tried to see if  your battery  works in another S4?
During the boot process, is the power cable connected?  Does it make a difference between the short boot time and whether or not a power cable is connected?

Comment: No cable is connected. i tried another battery.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into recovery mode and seeing if it turns of there

if it doesn't that means your software is corrupt and a factory reset/format cache from recovery mode might fix it

to access recovery mode hold power button+ volume up + home button at the same time while the device is off

Comment: *your software is corrupt* -- In particular, which software is this which can be dealt with a simple reset?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a app or setting that Is causing the system to not function or conflicting with it. no harm in trying , worth a try if nothing else works.

Comment: Can you improve your answer by adding details, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting it on a table on the power button or using n air compressor the power button is most likely stuck

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Most likely it's the power button problem, where it's always stucked inside, or depressed in. That makes your phone turns on then turns off by itself. I had the same problem. I found this great video on how to fixes it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l_6fwzuIwA

Comment: Consider adding the info from the video into the answer, since 1) not everyone has good internet access to play a video, 2) if the video goes down the worth of your answer would decrease considerably.